# Trying to get property of non-object (View: ) laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

tengo la vista de un foro donde mando a llamar al Auth para retomar el avatar (un string) del usuario:

```
<div class="chatter_avatar">
    <?php $usuario = Auth::user()->avatar ?>
    <img src="/img/avatars/{{ $usuario }}" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; float: left; border-radius: 50%; margin-left: -10px; margin-top: -7px;">
</div>
```

antes lo tenia así:

```
<div class="chatter_avatar">
    <img src="/img/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; float: left; border-radius: 50%; margin-left: -10px; margin-top: -7px;">
</div>
```

de igual manera, al entrar al link que me lleva al foro me sale este error

Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\Proyecto\resources\views\vendor\chatter\home.blade.php)

trate con Config::get pero no logre obtener resultados, que me recomiendan?
al hacer un dd, me muestra null

Comment: como haría el dd, perdon soy nuevo en laravel

Comment: dd (Auth::user() ) ????

Comment: pues lo agregue así: $usuario = dd(auth()->user() ) y si me envia a la vista del foro pero esta todo chueco y sin acomodo jaja y dicel null por parte del dd

Comment: intenta con `auth()->user()->avatar`

Comment: si el dd te muestra null es que no estas en una sesion

Comment: Pues me fui directamente a agregar en el controlador del foro en el constructor el middleware del Auth para que no puedan entrar al foro sin antes ingresar, aun asi gracias :)